# Undefined method using junction table

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, junction-table

I am getting the following error, and I can't seem to work out how to resolve the issue

```
undefined method `menu_attribute_value' for #<MenuAttribute:0x007f969a30c270>

%section.block-list
      - @attr.each do |attrs, values|
        %header= attrs
        %ul
          - values.each do |value|
            %li
              %input{:checked => '', name: value.id, type: 'radio', value: value, id: value}
                %label{:for => value}= value.menu_attribute_value
```

Controller

```
# GET /menu_items/1
  # GET /menu_items/1.json
  def show
    @menu_item = MenuItem.find(params[:id])
    @menu_item_attr = @menu_item.menu_attributes
    @attr = @menu_item_attr.group_by { |a| a.name }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.haml
      format.json { render json: @menu_item }
    end
  end
```

MenuAttribute Model

```
class MenuAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :menu_item
  belongs_to :venue

  def menu_attribute_params
    params.require(:menu_attribute).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

MenuItemAttribute Model

```
class MenuAttributesItems < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :menu_attribute_id, :menu_attribute_value, :menu_item_id, :venue_id

  belongs_to :menu_attribute
  belongs_to :menu_item
  belongs_to :venue


  def menu_attributes_items_params
    params.require(:menu_attributes_items).permit(:menu_attribute_value)
  end

end
```

Comment: You are calling `.menu_attribute_value` in your view on a `MenuAttribute` object. What does `MenuAttribute`look like ?

Comment: there is no `.menu_attribute_value` in there which explains the error and params.require(:menu_attribute).permit(:name) should be in the controller

Comment: I've added the model, so the params should be in the control now instead of the model